# Hey guys, I have a question about differentiability of the function of two variables

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Is the function
$$ f(x, y) = \begin{cases}y^2 \over x^2 + y^2 & (x,y) \neq (0, 0) \newline
 0 & (x, y) = (0, 0)\end{cases} $$
differentiable at $(0,0)$?

The thing is that first we have checked for function's continuity and it turned out that $\lim_{k \to 0} f(k,0)=0$ and $\lim_{k \to 0} f(0,k) \to 1$ which basically implies a discontinuity of our initial function which in turn asserts the impossibility of our function being differentiable. But it seems too easy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it without continuity:

$$
\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\|(x,y)\|}=\frac{\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}=\frac{y^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{3/2}}.
$$

Consider what happens to this quotient as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ from the $x$- versus the $y$-axis.

But your way is indeed easier, since differentiability implies continuity, and your limit is easier to examine.